# How do I attach a field from a related object to a Django queryset?

Tags: django

We are on Django 1.5 (for now, until the boss can be convinced otherwise...)

The app has multiple objects that reference each other as foreign keys:

```
class Result(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Quiz(models.Model):
    quiz_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=TYPE_POST)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)

class Lesson(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)

class LessonStatus(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson)
    attempts_remaining = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    passed = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

For reporting, I need to get all Results for a specified user (or users), apply some filters based on user input, and then display a table with data that includes fields from User, Quiz, Lesson, and Unit. (It also checks LessonStatus for some display options.)

Right now, most of the foreign key queries are being done in a loop in the template, which is.. bad. I tried using select_related - my query log shows that it is successfully doing the table joins, but doesn't actually assign the fields to anything, so it seems that when I reference a related field, it's still causing a new query.

I have found similar questions, where the answers suggested using annotate, but that's not working for me.

I have tried:

```
r = Result.objects.filter(user__in=students).filter(~Q(quiz__quiz_type='3'))
r.annotate(qt=F('quiz__quiz_type'))
```

but that gets me : 'F' object has no attribute 'lookup'. This is the same whether or not I do a select_related('quiz').  What am I doing wrong?

Adding code from view:

```
    r = Result.objects.filter(user__in=students).filter(~Q(quiz__quiz_type='3'))
                   r.select_related('quiz').select_related('user').select_related('lesson').select_related('unit')
if test_type != 'all':
    r = r.filter(Q(quiz__quiz_type=test_type))
               quiz__quiz_type='3')
if grade != 'any':
    r = r.filter(Q(quiz__lesson__unit__grades=grade))
#more filters
for test in r:
    if test.quiz.quiz_type == "1":
        tu = test.user_id
        try:
        status = LessonStatus.objects.get(user=tu, lesson=test.quiz.lesson.id)
```

My expectation was that when I do the select_related, it shouldn't need to do additional queries for the related objects. However, I'm seeing queries on Quiz in that forloop, so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Template:
(in a loop of for result in results)
    
        {{result.user.first_name|title}} {{result.user.last_name|title}}
    
    
        {{ result.quiz.lesson.title }}
      
      
          {{ result.quiz.lesson.unit.title }}
      
      
          {{ result.quiz.get_quiz_type_display }}

Query log is showing queries for each lesson and unit, so again, I'm doing something horribly wrong..

Comment: If your boss won't upgrade from an insecure and unsupported five-year-old version of your critical software, you need to find a new job.

Comment: However, your question is unclear. What does "not actually assign the fields to anything" mean? If you are using select_related, then following the relationship in the template will not cause another query. If that's not happening, you are doing somethng wrong, but you need to show the view and template where you are doing this. (That use of annotate won't work in such an old version, do you need to fix your initial approach.)

Comment: I've edited with additional code. I agree I'm doing something wrong, I'm just not sure what. This may be what convinces him to let me upgrade. He doesn't really understand what Django is (I was originally told the code was in PHP), and I inherited the app. He tends to prioritize tasks that he can see the result of so... I'm trying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow the relationships on the select_related call itself; lesson and unit are not fields on Result, so will be ignored. It should be:

```
 Result.objects.filter(...).select_related("quiz__lesson__unit", "user")
```

Comment: Thanks! That got rid of the multiple queries to quiz.  Follow up - is there a way to get LessonStatus in that same query? Can't quite get my brain around the notation on that one.

Comment: The link between quiz and lessonstatus is a reverse relation, so you'll need to use `.prefetch_related('quiz__lessonstatus')`. That performs a separate query, but it's a single one for all the statuses.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I'm assuming that's because there's no direct relationship between Result and LessonStatus. They both have foreign keys to user, and to Lesson (via Quiz for Result), but no keys to each other. Thanks again though, I will contemplate how I can get the info I need without the query in a loop thing.